# dynamically creating a diagram/layout

Tags: html, css, perl

So I just got an internship at this company, and as a side project, they want me to redesign one of their webpages. On their webpage, they have an image like the following:

[image: Crude Layout Diagram]

Basically, this is an image of a room layout, with different server boxes (white squares) used for testing. When you click on one of the white boxes, it will hyperlink you to a page that has to do with that server box and so forth. The issue is that if they redesign the room, or add server boxes etc, they need to remake a new image, and then change quite a bit of coordinates in a badly written perl script. (I thought this was a bad way to do things, and I recommended trashing the entire image idea in the first place, but they wanted to keep it). Anyway, is there an easier way to do this with code, so that if changes need to be changed, it only involves adding/subtracting lines of code? I was thinking of using some sort of html/css combination, but I don't know if there is a better way to go about doing this... I want to make there diagram a bit more dynamic.

Thank you.

Comment: In your data source, store each server as a server ID, a pair of coordinates, a length, and a width.  Then render the image programatically.  Use the stored coordinates in your image map.  Possibly store the image and detect a change in a coordinate checksum to render the stored image stale.  This is where most authors say, "Implementation is left as a practice for the reader." ;)

Comment: But how do I render an image "programatically"? And I like the idea.

Comment: So I did some extra research, and it turns out I can do something similar to what I'm saying with something called the python image library (PIL), but the issue is that I'm not allowed to install extra libraries on the web server (They have a lot of software restriction policies). Do you see any other way?

Comment: Hmm... If your hands are tied in such a way, how about setting up a table with background colors and grid-lines only visible where you need them.  What a pain, but light on dependencies.

Comment: As an intern, I doubt they'll let you do a rewrite.  See what libraries are installed for Perl.  Perl will have some libraries prelinked in the distro.  Just change little bits of the script at a time and doc your changes. Load your graphics extents from a file. It's trivial in Perl to load key=>value pairs from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Image Magick is often installed on web servers. Have a look at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php